# PC/Windows equivalent of "Fake"

Tags: webautomation

Doing some web testing and need a way to fill out forms automatically without much user interference. For OSX there is Fake [(FakeApp.com)](http://www.fakeapp.com) but is there an equivalent for Windows systems that are not Firefox/Chrome extensions?

Comment: Good question! I would like to have a FakeApp for Windows too. A point-and-click tool. While programmatically control might be an option, in my case the UI of FakeApp is perfect for my (simple) use case.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium RC? It's a UI scripting host commonly used for exactly what you want to do; automated UI testing of websites. It's browser-independent; just needs JavaScript enabled.

Comment: This looks interesting. Will have to pay with it some. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google's toolbar has autofill.
Although that might fall under your category of extensions.

Comment: Yeah, that's not usable. We're talking about filling out 20+ forms in a short amount of time (not stress testing but lots of forms). Takes on average about 45 minutes right now...